# Replacing a blender circuit breaker

Tags: motor, appliances

I'm replacing a blender's circuit breaker.
750W -Blender 
Current breaker is rated at 2.8A ~230V
So the maximum power output is 640W

But the blender itself is rated at 750W.
So the lower rated breaker would mean the blender would never reach 750W.

Is this done to help with heat dissipation?
How would it affect the blender if I went with a 3.x A ~230V breaker instead of a 2.8A breaker?

Comment: There is more to the breaker than just amps/volts. There are different curves that allow inrush currents or spikes without tripping.

Comment: General advice is to always replace protective devices with the same type  and rating. Have you heard of "Sears Horsepower"?